# Corrupt Storyboard

Tags: xcode4.5, uistoryboard

Happily working in (as much as you can ever be happy in) Xcode 4.5.2 when modifying a storyboard, Xcode crashed.

Ok, no worries, Xcode crashes all the time.  Restart it we are stuck.  I get the little spinner in the middle of Xcode as it attempts to open the three tabs I had open.  But eventually stops responding.

After I force quit, I notice a single process that is still left running:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool --socketFD 30
```

I can `sudo kill -9` this process all I want, but every time I open this project in Xcode, repeat performance.

Using the `alt+shift+click` trick for Xcode in the dock, I can open up a blank instance an open a different project just fine.  No issues loading the storyboard view or anything.

I traced the issue to the one iPad storyboard I was working on.  After doing Google research I opened up the storyboard in another editor and changed changed `useAutolayout="YES"` to `useAutolayout="NO"` and I was able to open the storyboard just fine in Xcode ... but none of my objects were there.

I could keep on pontificating... but I'm really hoping one of you have seen this before.  Thanks!

Comment: I was never able to fix this issue and have since recreated the storyboard from scratch.  Unfortunate but the way it had to be at the time.  If anyone else comes across it, would love to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but I had a similar experience. One thing I noticed was if I edited the Storyboard manually to disable AutoLayout, the UI objects were all still in the Storyboard, just with a height / width of 0. Not terribly helpful, as you still pretty much have to recreate everything from scratch (or at least since the last saved working version).

Comment: Thanks for this. I bet this was exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode was crashing at load for me due to one pesky little misplaced tablecell. I couldn't load the program at all or import the storyboard and every solution I saw online failed. What I did was delete the story board, open the project, and then restored the most recent snapshot (always take snapshots!). It imported the previous storyboard and I hardly lost any work.